# How do I populate a plist into a UITableView - ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist

First of all, I know the title has the potential to get me a downvote, but please red this question before that judgement is made:-)

I have a Plist with data, I have filled that out for now - as in the future I wish for the app to be able to populate this, but that is the next step.

I have sought for a long time the answer on how to do it, and thought that the terms (or along the lines off) IOS TUTORIAL - How to populate a UITableView with a plist - would do the trick, but nothing helpful has come up.

Has anyone on here got a tutorial I could follow, I am not here trying to leach for answers without the study, I am just a bit stuck:-)

I have Xcode 4.3.1 and I am designing the app for a minimum of an 5.0 iOS device - so that way I can keep the code to that spectrum.

Any help is awesome:-)

Jeff

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you access the plist from within your code? Can you create and populate a table view? It's a two part problem - there are a million tutorials for populating a table view using an array as the data source, and making an array from a plist is a single line of code. To get useful answers you'd need to be more specific - the structure of your plist and the desired structure of your table view would be a good start, as well as something to indicate what you have actually attempted before coming here.

Comment: I got it working:-) I have populated the table with data from a Plist - Sorry my question was so vague, I just didn't know how else to word it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a class method to do it?:

```
+(NSArray *)plistToArray {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"MyPListFile" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];


    NSArray *retArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dictobjectForKey:@"MyPListRootEntry"]];
    return retArr;
}
```